# Unusual reboots on gaming PC

Tags: reboot, windows-installer, build, corsair

I built my own gaming PC, but it reboots and I don't know why. It doesn't show a blue screen in Windows, or anything similar, it just turns off and then on.

Here are the specs of my PC loaded with CPU-Z:

https://valid.x86.fr/z9rv5v?fbclid=IwAR1OOI-YHKCRjyVmZoZBR78Sx1LBT08LJa-K0FnOZXTfxQWogIvwiPHufpA

These specs that are not on the webpage:

- Corsair H75 liquid cooling
- Corsair CX750M

I've tried increasing the GPU fan speed with [MSI Afterburner](https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner), setting the fan speed to automatic with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php), and restoring the default BIOS settings.

It's my first time building a PC, can someone help? I just want it to work properly.

Comment: I hate to ask but did you apply thermal paste to the CPU and did you remove any plastic on the heatsink base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the system is rebooting but not showing a BSOD, the BSOD may simply not have enough time to display before the system restarts.  I think you can still use SysInternal's BlueScreenView to view past bluescreens in Windows 10.  The Event Viewer will also log bluescreens (look for lines that say "BugCheck" under the System log).

Check the UEFI firmware for any logs, if the firmware shut off the system the reason may be logged there.  You can also check the Windows Event Viewer (again the System log) for clues on what was running before the shutoff to try to narrow down a cause.

Random power offs like this are typically hardware related.  You may need to remove all removeable hardware from your system (1 RAM stick, storage device that the OS is installed on, and no graphics card) and run it for a while to see if it spontaneously reboots.  If things seem stable, keep adding hardware until you find what is making it reboot.

Comment: To add to this answer. I've noticed that a random shutdown or restart with out a warning are usually power supply related. I recommend you start by troubleshooting there.